# Running cron jobs under php ver. 5.4

Tags: cron, php

My hosting company switched me to php version 5.4. I run a Drupal site (D7.) They say:

*You'll want to make sure your crons use "/usr/php/54/usr/bin/php" instead, as otherwise it will use PHP 5.2.*

How do I do that?

Change the php.ini file? Create a new file?

What is the exact syntax for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can either call them by specifying the interpreter to load the scripts in the crontab, with this syntax:

```
* * * * * /usr/php/54/usr/bin/php yourscript.php
```

Or, alternatively, if you are comfortable modifying the scripts, you can use a shebang line on top of it. To use the shebang line you just need to modify the first line of the script to look like this:

```
#!/usr/php/54/usr/bin/php
```

Then you need to make the script executable with `chmod +x yourscript.php` and then you can directly call it without specifying the interpreter like:

```
* * * * * yourscript.php
```

Here is more documentation about the shebang line: [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)

In many cases I think probably the first way (specifying the interpreter in the crontab) would be preferred, because it doesn't require you to modify the script itself.

Comment: Does this look alright?  0  *  *  *  *  wget -O - -q -t 1 /usr/php/54/usr/bin/php domainname/cron.php?cron_key=NRRPBAkGsf35jgwteIS4vp2XQJBlLGTYE13bDUAPZlo? The numbers are a Drupal key to run cron from outside the site.